# Проверить доступность серверов на c#

Tags: c#

Имеется несколько компьютеров с 3g модемами, на них должен быть запущен apache(порт 8080). Как проверить что apache запущен на каждом из них. Visual studio 2013 c#.

Comment: WAN IP-адреса статические? Порты с внешки доступны (проброшены через NAT и брендмауэр, если он есть)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте (для каждого IP-адреса)

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://A.B.C.D:8080/");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // failed
}
response.Close();
```

Если нет гарантий, что адреса буду всегда одни и те же, можно использовать какую-нибудь службу DDNS. Тогда вместо IP-адресов можно использовать FQDN.

Comment: Есть небольшая проблема. Вот так он видит http://m01:8080/, а вот так нет http://m01.company.internal:8080/

Comment: Что на выходе `ping m01.company.internal` и `nslookup m01.company.internal` (в `cmd`)? Должен быть актуальный IP-адрес. Сравните с выводом `ping m01` и `nslookup m01`

Comment: Нашли проблему на сервере. Но появился еще один вопрос. Если опрашиваемых сервером много, то есть смысл выполнять такие проверки в отдельных потоках? И такие проверки все-равно выполняются очень долго, можно ли как-то ускорить процесс?

Comment: Разумеется, но есть тонкости. Например, может не хватать свободных сокетов **на клиенте**. Придется менять `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\MaxUserPort` и/или `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\TCPTimedWaitDelay`

Comment: Насчет "долго" - тут происходит запрос страницы `/`, если она большая при слабой сети (3G) или долго генерируется, то можно запрашивать какой-нибудь файл (favicon или логотип сайта, к примеру) : `WebRequest.Create("http://m01/logo.png")`